# What residuals are used when testing for auto-correlation with time series data?

Tags: time-series, t-test, autocorrelation

I'm looking to compare two sets of time series data via T-test (let's call them X and Y) to see if there's a statistically significant difference in means. I understand (I think) the need to test for auto-correlation to ensure there's no correlation between residuals of the regression. What I'm not understanding is what residuals are being referred to here.

Would this be the residuals from the regression of X vs Y? I'm unclear on what's considered the "predictor" here as I'm not trying to fit a model to the time series data.

Comment: they are testing to see if the two series are correlated but , the test should involved X and Y ONLY AFTER ANY EFFECTS THAT CAN BE MODELLED ARE ELIMINATED. For example, both the Y and X series might have arima representations so you'd want to fit an arima model first ( to each one ) , test those residuals and see if they have any autocorrelation. If not, then you can use the residuals ( of each one ) as the TRANSFORMED Y  series and the TRANSFORMED X series and do t-tests on those series. You use the term "regression" in your question so maybe your regression refers to any time series model.

Comment: Hi: You can google for the term "transfer response"  because I think that's the more general version of what I tried to explain above. Anything you find will hopefully be clearer and more detailed.